# Prove that $X^2$ is random variable in case that $X$ is random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

- Show that if $X$ is a random variable $X^2$ is also a random variable.
  How should I prove that, why wouldn't that be true? (no additional information is given)
- Show that if $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are random variables on the same distribution space than $\text{sup}_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}X_n$ is also random variable

Comment: What is the definition of random variable with which you are working with?

Comment: if you define random variables as measurable functions it follows trivially from the fact that both functions , square and sup are measurable functions

Comment: @Keen-ameteur No further info is given I assume that $X$ is a continuous random variable.

Comment: In basic probability that I'm familiar with, $X$ is a Random variable if $\{ \omega :X(\omega)\leq a \}$ is an event for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Have you been given this definition at some point?

Comment: How rigorous of a course is this? Do you treat probability spaces as measure spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove the first one, we split into three cases:

If $a\in\mathbb{R}_{<0}$ then $$\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)^{2}>a\}=\varnothing\ \text{which is measurable}.$$

If $a=0$. then $$\{\omega\in\Omega:X^{2}>a\}=\{\omega\in\Omega:X^{2}>0\}=\Omega\ \text{which is also measurable}.$$

Finally, if $a\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, you have 
\begin{align*}
\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)^{2}>a\}&=\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)>\sqrt{a}\ \text{or}\ X(\omega)<-\sqrt{a}\}\\
&=\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)>\sqrt{a}\}\cup\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)<-\sqrt{a}\},
\end{align*}
but $X$ is a random variable, implying the above two sets measurable, and thus the union of them are measurable.

Thus, $\{\omega\in\Omega:X^{2}(\omega)>a\}$ is measurable for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and thus $X^{2}$ is a random variable.

---

For the second one, I am gonna firstly show that $\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_{n}$ is a random variable.

Note that the infimum of a sequence $\leq a$ if and only if some terms is $\leq a$, and thus $$\{\omega\in\Omega:\inf_{n}X_{n}\leq a\}=\bigcup_{n}\{\omega\in\Omega:X_{n}\leq a\}.$$ Each set in the above countable union is measurable since $X_{n}$ is measurable and thus so is their countable union.

A similarly argument will show that $$\{\omega:\sup_{n}X_{n}>a\}=\bigcup_{n}\{\omega:X_{n}> a\},$$ is measurable. Equivalently, you could also argue with  $$\{\omega:\sup_{n}X_{n}\leq a\}=\bigcap_{n}\{\omega:X_{n}\leq a\},$$ since this is just taking complement with De Morgan's Law.

---

By the way, with the result for your second question, i.e. $\sup_{n}X_{n}$ and $\inf_{n}X_{n}$ are measurable, you could also show that $\limsup X_{n}$ and $\liminf X_{n}$ are random variable:

Firstly we have the following relations: $$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_{n}=\sup_{n}\Big(\inf_{m\geq n}X_{m}\Big)$$ and $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_{n}=\inf_{n}\Big(\sup_{m\geq n}X_{m}\Big).$$

Using the similar proof we made to your second question, it is easy to see that  the functions defined by $$Y_{n}:=\inf_{m\geq n}X_{m}\ \text{and}\ Z_{n}:=\sup_{m\geq n}X_{m}$$ are both random variables for all $n$, but then $$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_{n}=\sup_{n}Y_{n}\ \text{and}\ \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_{n}=\inf_{n}Z_{n}$$ are both random variables, by your second question.

Comment: Thank you for your informative explanation!

Comment: @AvivSham No problem :) By the way, the proof for your first question can be applied to many other cases. See if you can apply the same proof to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533219/show-that-n-t-sup-ns-n-leq-t-is-a-stochastic-process-with-time-mat (this is to prove $N_{t}$ is a random variable, for fixed $t$) Enjoy!

Comment: I will read it ASAP. as for the $\text{sup}X_n$ if the $\text{inf}$ case is a random variable then a finite number of intersections which describe the whole distribution space $\Omega$ must be a random variable, isn't it?

Comment: @AvivSham ah! For the $\sup$, I am sorry for pointing you to a wrong direction. I will edit my proof.

Comment: @AvivSham edited! so the the $\sup X_{n}$, you should take countable intersection $$\{\omega:X_{n}\leq a\}=\bigcap_{n}\{\omega:X_{n}\leq a\}$$ which is the same thing in my proof (I took the countable union but I analyzed the complement).

Comment: @JacobsonRadical, do you have a book to learn the basics of this?

Comment: @AlvaroMorales The proof of properties of random variable is basically the proof of properties of measurable functions. So you can pick any measure theory book. For random variable and probability theory, you can try Amir Dembo's note: https://adembo.su.domains/stat-310b/lnotes.pdf. For book, you can try A.N. Shiryaev's probability and probability 2 --- really good books.

Comment: @AlvaroMorales You can also take a look of my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497009/measure-theory-and-topology-books-that-have-solution-manuals/4060789#4060789 about the book of measure theory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to see that $X^2$ is a random variable.

The composition of measurable functions is measurable, which is trivially seen from the definition of measurability.

Since $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto x^2$ is continuous, it is measurable (the inverse of an open is again open, in particular measurable). Thus

$$X^2 = f\circ  X$$ 
is also measurable, and thus a random variable.